# How can I create a PDF Layer in a CGPDFPage?

Tags: swift, layer, cgpdfdocument

I am trying to generate a print compatible layered PDF page.  Currently I am using the CGPDFDocument to render the PDF file but it is not clear whether it is possible to create PDF layers - or Optional Content Groups (OCG) as I believe they are known.

Any pointers on how to do this ?

EDIT:

Some progress here -

Currently for the spot layers I am importing a PDF file page containing the required spot colour and scaling it to fill the required area.

For imported logos the logos are generated with the required spot colour - actually it is just a custom colour space with a specific label used by the print process.  For example PMS 431C (Pantone)

Ideally I would like to be able to create this in code but I don't know how to create a custom colour space and then use the colour from that colour space. A different question perhaps.

Comment: @KJ the layers are used by the print process - e.g. spot layers for solid colour ink